# Kotlin coroutines 1.6.4 - async unresolved

Tags: kotlin, async-await, kotlin-coroutines, jooq

I'm trying to upgrade add coroutines support to Kotlin/Spring-boot service.
Currently I'm trying to wrap DB calls (using jooq) with async context.

My problem is that I'm getting unresolved errors for `async/await` (also to `GlobalScope.async`) and `.await()` jooq extensions.

Gradle settings I tried (and didn't work):

```
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor:1.6.4")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactive:1.6.4")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8:1.6.4")
    implementation("org.jooq:jooq-kotlin-coroutines:3.17.2")
```

**build.gradle.kts:**

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.5.2"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.21"
    id("nu.studer.jooq") version "5.0"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.5.20"
}

group = "com.lumen.server"
version = "2.0"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:6.6")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.9.0")
    implementation("io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:1.7.8")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq")
    implementation(platform("com.netflix.graphql.dgs:graphql-dgs-platform-dependencies:latest.release"))
    implementation("com.netflix.graphql.dgs:graphql-dgs-spring-boot-starter")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc")
//    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("junit:junit:4.13.1")
    implementation("com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sqs:1.12.257")
    implementation("org.springframework:spring-messaging:5.3.21")
    implementation("io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-messaging:2.4.1")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor:1.6.4")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactive:1.6.4")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8:1.6.4")
    //implementation("org.jooq:jooq-kotlin-coroutines:3.17.2")
    jooqGenerator("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.6")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("io.mockk:mockk:1.10.5")
    testImplementation("org.jeasy:easy-random-core:4.3.0")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: This might be a hint: `coroutineScope` is also unresolved

Comment: Just to be sure, did you declare those `implementation` dependencies in `dependencies`? Can you share a bit more from your `build.gradle`?

Comment: Hi @LukasEder, thanks for replying - added the gradle file above.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving only `implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8:1.6.4")` and removing the other dependencies from the build did the trick